# Zip file in windows using commands in python

Tags: python

Trying to zip files using commands in python.

When i run Compress-Archive logs logs.zip, it works on my powershell.

However, when i run the command on my python script, it is not working and does not even throw any error message.

```
cmd = "Compress-Archive logs logs.zip"
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", cmd])
```

I am using this command because i do not have to install anything to zip a file.

Update: This command works. It didn't throw out any error message because it didn't even run in the first place. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to zip a file

```
import zipfile
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('yourfile.zip', 'w')
zip_file.write('yourown.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zip_file.close()
```